# Battery usage settings, allow app to run programmatically in background

Tags: android, android-studio

This question has been asked before, but no working answer has been made.

In android Settings-> App Management -> App(Selected) -> Battery usage.
We find 3 options :
[image]

How we can programmatically (with code) enable option 1 ( run in background), if we can't, how to redirect user to this page ?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

> In android Settings-> App Management -> App(Selected) -> Battery usage. We find 3 options

There are tens of thousands of Android device models. Whether that screen exists, and what its options are, will depend on the model.

> How we can programmatically (with code) enable option 1 ( run in background)

That is not an option, sorry. If it were, every app would use it.

> if we can't, how to redirect user to this page ?

You can try [`ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings?hl=en#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS). Note that it requires `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` as a permission, and that in turn might require additional documentation when you go to distribute your app.